# Load swf at last frame

Tags: actionscript-3

Can anyone help? I have several swfs that need a back button and go to the last frame of the previous swf. I can get it to load but I can't get it it to go to a certain frame(the last frame of the swf to be specific). How do I add code to go to that frame? Here is the code:

```
lastPage2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_1);

import fl.display.ProLoader;
var fl_ProLoader_1:ProLoader;

var fl_ToLoad_1:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  if(fl_ToLoad_1)
  {
  fl_ProLoader_1 = new ProLoader();
  fl_ProLoader_1.load(new URLRequest("CEAS_I_1_16.swf"));
  addChild(fl_ProLoader_1);
   }
  else
  {
  fl_ProLoader_1.unload();
  removeChild(fl_ProLoader_1);
  fl_ProLoader_1 = null;
  }
  fl_ToLoad_3 = !fl_ToLoad_1;

}
```

Comment: looks like you are looking for something like `mc.gotoAndStop(mc.totalFrames)` http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndStop%28%29

Answer (score 0):

[`mc.gotoAndStop`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndStop%28%29)([`mc.totalFrames`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#totalFrames)) should help